# adding 2 more dimensions to tensor

Tags: pytorch

I am getting the following error message:

**RuntimeError: w groups=3, expected weight to be at least 3 at dimension 0, but got weight of size [1, 1, 2, 2] instead**

when i try to convolve a image with a filter using the "functional version of conv2d"

i know why i am receiving this error message... it is because i need to have 3 dimensions in channel 0. But i have now i idea how to add two more dimensions.

I have flailed around for quite some time trying to add two more, but i cant figure it out. I want to the kernal applied one all color channels... so i just want to replicate it 2 more times.

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as nnf
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms

img = Image.open("GOPR0305.jpg")

preprocess = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
img_t = preprocess(img)
img_t = torch.unsqueeze(img_t, 0)

hci = [1, -1]
hri = [-1, 1]

hc = [1.0, -1.0]
hr = [-1.0, 1.0]

lc = [0.5, 0.5]
lr = [0.5, 0.5]



hh_k = torch.tensor([hc ,hr])[None, None, ...]
hl_k = torch.tensor([hc ,lr])[None, None, ...]
lh_k = torch.tensor([lc ,hr])[None, None, ...]
ll_k = torch.tensor([lc ,lr])[None, None, ...]
in_t = torch.tensor([ [14, 7, 6, 2,] , [4 ,8 ,11 ,1], [3, 5, 9 ,10], [12, 15, 16, 13] ])[None, None, ...]
in_t = torch.tensor([ [14.0, 7.0, 6.0, 2.0,] , [4.0 ,8.0 ,11.0 ,1.0], [3.0, 5.0, 9.0 ,10.0], [12.0, 15.0, 16.0, 13.0] ])[None, None, ...]

def wave_haar(in_t):
    hh = nnf.conv2d(in_t, hh_k,stride=2,groups=3)
    ll = nnf.conv2d(in_t, ll_k,stride=2)
    hl = nnf.conv2d(in_t, hl_k,stride=2)
    lh = nnf.conv2d(in_t, lh_k,stride=2)
    return [ll,hl,lh,hh]
    
[ll,hl,lh,hh] = wave_haar(img_t[:,2:])

print(img_t.shape)
print(img_t.size())
print(img_t)
print(img_t.shape)
print(ll.shape)
```

Comment: please describe _mathematically_ what you are trying to do. The code you added does not contribute to understanding your question. Make the code example short and clear that directly reproduces the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

changing the group of the first layer to 1 fixed the problem for me like this

```
def wave_haar(in_t):
    hh = nnf.conv2d(in_t, hh_k,stride=2,groups=1)
    ll = nnf.conv2d(in_t, ll_k,stride=2)
    hl = nnf.conv2d(in_t, hl_k,stride=2)
    lh = nnf.conv2d(in_t, lh_k,stride=2)
    return [ll,hl,lh,hh]
```

Comment: Yes, but if i do that its only convolving one of the color channels of the image... i want a way to convovle are three color channels?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, by chaning the kernal to be 3-dimensions:

from

```py
hh_k = torch.tensor([hc ,hr])[None, None, ...]
```

```py
hh_k3 = torch.tensor([[[hc, hr]],[[hc, hr]],[[hc, hr]]])
```